# Azure Search service set up

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Hello I am trying to create a new azure search service with S2 or S3 tier.

However, as I try to create, I am getting validation error:
Any idea how to resolve this?

below are raw error details:

```
{
  "telemetryId": "127e12a7-2de5-420d-8ce3-181a5e663337",
  "bladeInstanceId": "Blade_f10d818ac9854758a2308220f06e7274_5_0",
  "galleryItemId": "Microsoft.Search",
  "createBlade": "CreateBladeV3",
  "code": "InvalidTemplateDeployment",
  "message": "The template deployment 'Microsoft.Search' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is 'd2a97835-fd96-4b15-95f9-416e19086f31'. See inner errors for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "ServiceQuotaExceeded",
      "message": "Operation would exceed standard3 service quota"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like either the subscription you are using doesn't allow for paid services or you are trying to create an index in the service via import that is too large. However, S2 and S3 allow quite large indexes, so my guess is the former.

Comment: I am already using standard subscription s1..which is already a paid subscription. I want to create another search service with s2.